# Angular 2 redirect on click

Tags: javascript, redirect, angular

How to create simple redirect on click on some button in Angular 2? Already tried:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router'

@Component({
    selector: 'loginForm',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.navigate(['./SomewhereElse']);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could leverage the event support of Angular2:

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'loginForm',
  template: `
    <div (click)="redirect()">Redirect</div>
  `,
  providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  redirect() {
    this.router.navigate(['./SomewhereElse']);
  }
}
```

Comment: not working. I have EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot find default outlet

Comment: Could you provide the content of the template where you define routes (containing the `SomewhereElse` one)? You should have a `router-outlet` in it...

Comment: Yes I have it inside. It is inside app.component.ts.  @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <nav>
      <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
      <a [routerLink]="['/main-menu']">Main Menu</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

Comment: What is the configuration of routes for this component?

Comment: import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router'; import { LoginFormComponent } from './login-form.component';
import { MainMenuComponent } from './main-menu.component';

Comment: You don't have a `@RouteConfig` decorator?

Comment: No I haven't. Look [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) In Live example there is not such a thing

Comment: Okay, you use the new router. So a `@Routes` one ;-)?

Comment: @Routes([
  {path: '/dashboard',  component: LoginFormComponent},
  {path: '/main-menu',  component: MainMenuComponent}
])

Comment: No `SomewhereElse` defined in your `@Routes` block?

Comment: Yes, My outlet anchors works, I got this outlet error in console, and I am not able to implement click redirect in inner pages

Answer (score 16):

I would make it more dynamic using method parameters

Import the angular router

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

Create a button with click event

```
<div (click)="redirect(my-page)">My page</div>
```

Create a method with a pagename parameter

```
redirect(pagename: string) {
  this.router.navigate(['/'+pagename]);
}
```

When clicked the router should route to the correct page

Answer (score 11):

I'd say use `routerLink` directive & placed that over `a`(anchor) tag

```
<a [routerLink]="['./SomewhereElse']">Redirect</a>
```

<strike>Also you need to remove `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` from `providers` & include it in bootstrap dependency and then add `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` in directives option of component to use `routerLink` directive on HTML.</strike> Make sure `RouterModule` with its route has been injected in Main App module.

Comment: @TeodorKolev look at [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PMkIbCWJAAlxLBYgDcTG?p=preview) I took it from angular.io, which has many link created using `routerLink`

Comment: @SaiyaffFarouk what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Does this works to navigate with parameters? This is just to the simple redirection yeah?

Comment: @SaiyaffFarouk yes it is simple redirect, if you want to pass dynamic parameter, it could be `[routerLink]="['./somewhereelse', someId, someName]"`.. and if you want to pass query parameters, you could add `queryParams` attribute binding like `[queryParams]="{ page: 1 }"`

Answer (score 9):

Try `routerLink`on button tag

```
 <button type="button"  [routerLink]="['/edit']">Edit</button>
```

[More Info](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9471)

Comment: @atishshimpi Why not just: <button type="button" routerLink="/edit">Edit</button>? Why are you using the square brackets?

Comment: it's without brackets

Answer (score 0):

in your html file right this code.

```
<button (click)="btnClick()">Cancel</button>
```

in your component.ts file right this code.

```
constructor(private router:Router) { }
btnClick(){
this.router.navigateByUrl("/payment");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
window.location.reload();
```

does the trick

Comment: This will obviously not work because it's just reloading the page rather than redirecting.

Comment: it will reloading whole angular app