# Check for Internet connectivity in Angular2 (not Ionic) Cordova app

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript

We have created an Angular2 Cordova (not Ionic) app that makes many calls to backend services.

We would like the app to show a specific page (Component) if the user has no connection. We have that all built, however how do we sense the connectivity and then show the page?

The app is written in TypeScript, I was thinking I could add some code to the index.ts file to accomplish this, but the index.ts file doesn't understand the app's navigation to allow me to change the page.

I know I need the Cordova Network Information plugin and I know how to use that to check for connectivity, but the missing piece is hooking that up so that it can change the page (route to the appropriate component).

Comment: How about subscribing to the plugins `online` event and routing manually in the event handler like described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252146/angular-2-redirect-on-click#answer-37252182)?

Comment: What's the reason to avoid doing this in a service?

Comment: what's `index.ts` supposed to look like ?  what have you tried ? are you using `@angular/router` for routing ? what is the error ? you asked for suggestions not solutions, that's why answers are not satisfying enough, please add some `code related information` so that we can provide better solutions

Comment: I'm not sure how to accomplish it in a service. I guess, I could that, but then wouldn't I need to inject that service in all components? I guess I'm too much of a novice with Angular2 to know how that would work.

Comment: If you want to check internet connectivity when app starts, do it in the root component. If you want to check it on route change then you can subscribe to `router` for changes and you will not have to repeat the code anywhere else. If you want to check it on `http` requests then you will need a common service through which all the requests will actullay happen and you'll not have to repeate in every `http` request. I implemented the last one for our app.

Comment: Hi, Please give solution for my issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/44343585/3600674

Answer (score 0):

After you have install the Cordova Network Plugin this check every second:

```
setInterval(
    function(){
      if(!navigator || !navigator.network) return; //if is undefined

      if(navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE){
            alert("nocon");
        }else{
            alert("yescon");
        }
    }, 1000
);
```

Comment: The last paragraph of the question, "I know I need the Cordova Network Information plugin and I know how to use that to check for connectivity, but the missing piece is hooking that up so that it can change the page (route to the appropriate component)."

Comment: use `$setInterval` instead of `setInterval` inside a `run` method in your module. Inject `$state` in the run method and use `$state.go` instead of `alert("nocon");` or `alert("yescon");`

Comment: @gianlucatursi It's NOT an Angular 1.x project.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin provides an implementation of an old version of the [Network Information API](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/network/). It provides information about the device’s cellular and wifi connection, and whether the device has an internet connection.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

here is example for your

```
  module.controller('MyCtrl', function($rootScope, $cordovaNetwork) {

      document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

        var type = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork()

        var isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline()

        var isOffline = $cordovaNetwork.isOffline()


        // listen for Online event
        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState){
          var onlineState = networkState;
        })

        // listen for Offline event
        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState){
          var offlineState = networkState;
        })

      }, false);
    });
```

for further information Please visit the reference link

Comment: A few things...1. As I said, I'm using TypeScript. 2. I'm using Angular2.